# How count average from Excel using Python

Tags: python

How count time average from Excel using Python row b or c?

This my code

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('convert.xlsx')

t1 = pd.to_datetime(df['b'], format='%H:%M:%S')
t2 = pd.to_datetime(df['c'], format='%H:%M:%S')

delta = t2 - t1

print(delta)
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Convert `to_timedelta` instead of `to_datetime`

Answer (score 0):

You can use timedelta [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) that does not represent a date but a amount of time (a number of days, hours, month etc).

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('convert.xlsx')

t1 = pd.to_timedelta(df['b'], format='%H:%M:%S')
t2 = pd.to_timedelta(df['c'], format='%H:%M:%S')

delta = (t2 - t1)

avg = pd.Series(delta).mean()

print(avg)
```